# Strange feeling with my bi-directional JPA OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities, `User` and `Role`, which should be related in a bi-directional one `Role` to many `User`.

User class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;
    ...
    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
        if (!role.getUsers().contains(this)) {
            role.getUsers().add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The role class:

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long roleId;

    private String roleName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    public void addUser(User user) {
        users.add(user);
        if (user.getRole() != this) {
            user.setRole(this);
        }
    }
```

Finally I try to set these entities in my signUp-method this way:

```
    try {
        em.persist(newUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Could not persist user.");
    }

    Role role = new Role();
    role.setRoleName("user");
    role.addUser(newUser);
    try {
        em.persist(role);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Could not persist role.");
    }
```

So far everything is fine and I get no Exceptions, but somehow I have a feeling that there is some redundancy. I wondering what happens if I store always just one User in the `List<User>` in `Role`? Or am I being paranoid, and this code is fine?

Comment: You are being paranoid, there is nothing wrong with your mappings or sample code.

Comment: In most cases users and roles have many to many relationship but if your business requirement is to have just one role per user and never more a one-to-many should be fine. I don't think I would ever add a user to a role. I would just assign a role to a user.

Comment: @Shire Resident: You are right for sure. For simplicity(?) I tried it as first step with a OneToMany relationship, but I will change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` can have multiple roles, and one `Role` can belong to multiple users. You need to have a `@ManyToMany` association between `User` and `Role`. `Role` is something like reference value, so it shouldn't store associated users.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long pid;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Role> roles;

}

@Entity
@Table
public class Role {

    @Id
    private Long pid;

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

Comment: Heck, that looks even simpler than OneToMany. And as mentioned above I guess, Ill change that.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for up vote. I update with additional thoughts.

Comment: Now I tried it with ManyToMany and this works very fine (just for testing):
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRoleName("user");
        Role role2 = new Role();
        role2.setRoleName("admin");
        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
        roles.add(role);
        roles.add(role2);
        newUser.setRoles(roles);
        em.persist(newUser);

Comment: @Martin Keep in mind that `@ManyToMany` uses an additional join table. You need to create roles and after that find it and add to the user. Something like @Massahud answer. You can use an `enum` for it: `RoleEnum  (USER, ADMIN)`.

Answer (score 2):

Is seems like you are creating a new Role with name "user" for every new user, instead of reusing the current "user" Role. And every "user" role have only one user.

You should try to find the role by name instead of always creating a new Role.

```
    Role role = findRoleByName("user"); 
    if (role == null) {
        role = new Role();
        role.setRoleName("user");
    }

    role.addUser(newUser);
    try {
        em.persist(role);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Could not persist role.");
    }
```

Comment: Since roles are usually pre inserted on the database, you should not need the if (role == null) block